# line doesnt located inside the paintbox

Tags: forms, borland-c++, onpaint

I did:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)    
{    
  DrawingBoard = new Graphics::TBitmap;    
  DrawingBoard->Width = this->PaintBox1->Width;     
  DrawingBoard->Height = this->PaintBox1->Height;    
}

void __fastcall TForm1::PaintBox1Paint(TObject *Sender)
{     
        PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Color = clBlack;    
        Canvas->MoveTo(256,216);    
        Canvas->LineTo(270,250);    
}


void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)    
{      
      PaintBox1->Canvas->Draw(256, 216, DrawingBoard);
}
```

So I saw the line but not inside the paint box-why?

Answer (score 0):

1. **because you use `Canvas->` instead of `PaintBox1->Canvas->`**

   - so you draw on the `this->Canvas->` which is `Form1` in your case
2. **I assume you want to use bitmap as back buffer**

   - then you should use `DrawingBoard->Canvas` instead of all `PaintBox1->Canvas->`
   - except the last in `FormShow`
   - also I would use `OnPaint` instead of `OnShow` ...
   - also you should use client size not size
   - also do not draw bitmap offseted to `PaintBox` the VCL translate the coordinates by itself
   - do not forget to clear the backbuffer before rendering (unless you are doing some cumulative drawing/effect)

**Something like this:**

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)    
{    
  DrawingBoard = new Graphics::TBitmap;    
  DrawingBoard->Width =  PaintBox1->ClientWidth;     
  DrawingBoard->Height = PaintBox1->ClientHeight;    
}

void __fastcall TForm1::PaintBox1Paint(TObject *Sender)
{     
        DrawingBoard->Canvas->Pen->Color = clBlack;    
        DrawingBoard->Canvas->Brush->Color = clWhite;    
        DrawingBoard->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,DrawingBoard->Width,DrawingBoard->Height));
        DrawingBoard->Canvas->MoveTo(256,216);    
        DrawingBoard->Canvas->LineTo(270,250);    
        PaintBox1->Canvas->Draw(0,0,DrawingBoard);
}
```

**[Notes]**

- if your PaintBox is resize-able then add its OnResize event and resize the bitmap inside ...

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your detailed answer!